# Webpack CLI silently fails when running it on a .ts file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have a `webpack.config.js` file with a default entrypoint, i.e.:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve('./src/main.ts'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(j|t)sx?$/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
        ...
      },
      ...
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    ...
  },
  ...
};
```

Running `npx webpack` directly builds `main.ts` as expected. In addition, if I pass in an input file as an argument, it can build any `.js` files:

```
npx webpack someScript.js
```

However, with a `.ts` file, it ignores the input file argument and builds the default entrypoint instead. It doesn't even show a warning.

How can I get Webpack CLI to build a `.ts` file?

Comment: I think that you need a plugin right? You can see some info [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/)

Comment: I tried doing it with ts-loader and it works, you sure this isn't an babel-loader issue?https://imgur.com/a/7WxFfoA

Comment: What dependencies + versions are you using? Please provide a gist/text.

Comment: @kyle I tried removing sections from my Webpack config until I have the config in the question and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To build typescript files using webpack, I think this could be the best guide.
Please have a look at it and if it is not what you want, it would be better to make more clear your questions to discuss details.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Comment: That link makes no mention of Webpack CLI